# Any Option for Custom Paypal Login template

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Any Option for Custom Paypal Login template in paypal Dashboard
Any option for change Paypal logo in paypal connect [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU9p7.png)

Answer (score 0):

No. If you use the minibrowser option you can keep your site loaded in the background, so that is best.  It's an in-context login to PayPal.

Comment: is there any option for change logo in login page in pypal login (or any dashboard setting to change logo in paypal login)?

Comment: There is no option.